# Современный процессор читает комнды из EEPROM напрямую или сначала загружает в оперативную память? Как процессор читает данные из HDD/SSD?

Tags: bios, hdd, ssd, x86-64, uefi

Есть ли в материнке поминмо EEPROM Flash память? Из какой из них происходит чтение?
Напрямую или через посредника. Если через оперативку, то зачем это лишнее действие.
И каким образом процессор получает данные из SSH/HDD? Как я понимаю эти данные копируются в оперативную память, потом процессор оттуда читает их. А как они попадают в оперативную память? Есть какие-то команды в процессоре для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В:** Есть ли в материнке поминмо EEPROM Flash память? Из какой из них происходит чтение? Напрямую или через посредника. Если через оперативку, то зачем это лишнее действие.

**О:** Скорее всего, нет. ПЗУ читается напрямую. В современных процессорах всё равно есть буферизация, так что смысла в копировании в ОЗУ для увеличения бытсродействия нет. И там, в основном, находятся программы, используемые для инициализации устройств, то есть они не выполняются всё время.

**В:** И каким образом процессор получает данные из SSH/HDD? Как я понимаю эти данные копируются в оперативную память, потом процессор оттуда читает их. А как они попадают в оперативную память? Есть какие-то команды в процессоре для этого?

**О:** Процессор получает данные через порты ввода-вывода, для этого у процессора есть специальные команды. Для передачи больших массивов данных устройства на шине ввода-вывода используют прямой доступ в память и не задействуют процессор. Выглядит это примерно так: через соответствующие порты процессор отправляет в контроллер команды (где и сколько прочитать и куда положить); контроллер диска считывает данные с диска и записывает их в ОЗУ, а процессор потом берёт данные уже из ОЗУ.

**Дополнительная информация:** Для процессора внешний мир состоит из памяти (ОЗУ, куда в каких-то местах вклинивается ПЗУ устройств на шине) и портов ввода-вывода. И то и то адресуется. Обычные команды адресуют ОЗУ. Для доступа к портам существуют специальные команды, их всего две: прочитать данные из порта и записать данные в порт.

Возможен вариант, когда адресное пространство общее, а порты для доступа выбираются внешним контроллером (доступа к памяти) по адресу, т. е. если на каком-то адресе есть порт ввода-вывода, то при обращении процессора по этому адресу контроллер доступа отключает ОЗУ и подключает порт. Соответствующая ячейка ОЗУ просто не используется. Таким же образом осуществляется и доступ к ПЗУ вместо ОЗУ.

Comment: `контроллер диска считывает данные с диска` - на с диска, а из интерфейса (напр, SATA), а по ту сторону интерфейса ещё один ОЗУ буфер! (примерно мегабайт на 100), и там ещё один контроллер.

Comment: @ESkri - да, там может быть всё, что угодно, но ЦПУ к этому уже доступа не имеет.

Comment: имеет.  ЦПУ может обновить прошивку того внешнего контроллера )))

Comment: @ESkri не имеет. Прошивка обновляется так же, как и записываются данные на диск. Процессор записывает образ в ОЗУ и командует контроллеру обновить прошивку, взяв её по указанному адресу. Другой вариант - ПЗУ с прошивкой прямо в пространстве памяти ЦПУ, но такое сейчас уже не используется, по крайней мере, для дисков. Для BIOSа используется.

Comment: Добавьте в ответ, что говоря о процессоре вы рассказываете о "x86-совместимом" чипе, а не обо всех arm-ах, mips-ах и т.д.

Comment: @avp Это как раз обо всех процессорах. Процессорных архитертур много, и работать они могут по-разному, но общие принципы примерно такие. Что вас смутило? Не во всех системах есть контроллеры прямого доступа к памяти, например.

Comment: В большинстве систем нет специальных команд для обращения к портам ввода-вывода (они находятся в одном и том же адресном пространстве, что и все остальное (исключая управляющие регистры самого процессора) и для доступа к ним используются те же команды lr/sr, что и для доступа к обычной памяти)